# how to determine if the argument of a function passed into another function as an argument is undefined or not

Tags: javascript

If I have to make a function, say maybe() which takes in another function fn as argument, and return a new function when the argument of fn is not undefined or null, how should I determine if the argument of fn is undefined or not?

```
function maybe(fn) {
    return fn;
}

function fn(firstName, lastName) {
    return `${firstName} ${lastName}`; 
}

// this will print, firstName Lastname    
console.log(maybe(fn)("firstName","Lastname"));

// it will print undefined Lastname
console.log(maybe(fn)(undefined, "Lastname"));
```

How can I modify the maybe function to check if any of the argument for `fn` is `undefined` or `null` and return `false` if there is any?

I cannot make any modification to the `fn` function except the args I passed in, because `fn` is an external function that will be passed into `maybe` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have `maybe(fn)` return a wrapper function:

```
function maybe(fn) {
    return function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; ++i) {
            if (arguments[i] == null) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return fn.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
```

Comment: @QiuxuanChen If my answer helped, would you mind accepting my answer?